# Multiple columns in find() in yii

Tags: yii

I need to find name and address columns only from database
I am usinf the following query

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='name';
$criteria->select='address';
$criteria->condition="username=:username";
$criteria->addCondition("active=:active");
$criteria->params=array(':username'=>$this->username,':active'=>1);
$record=User::model()->find($criteria);
```

But I am geting only `'address'`in the output. How can I get both column results? Is there anything similar like  `addCondition()` for specifying wanted columns only for  select also ?

Comment: what do you mean by both column results? you specify address in select, so you get only the address key

Comment: I need to get name and address, but it is giving only address

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your select requirements with commas instead of placing them separately.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='name,address';
$criteria->condition="username=:username";
$criteria->addCondition("active=:active");
$criteria->params=array(':username'=>$this->username,':active'=>1);
$record=User::model()->find($criteria);
```